# How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in verilog?

Tags: verilog

In a case statement case(s), the nvalue of s is increased by the power of 2.

```
input[127:0] s 
output[127:0] y

case(s)
  128'b1: y=a1; 
  128'b2: y=a2;
...
```

When it goes to 2^64, the number is so big and it will be represented automatically by scientific notation, eg.

```
128'b1.84467e19: y=a64
```

This will give me a syntax error, is there a way to avoid this?

I don't want to define it as real, since I want to synthesise this code.

Comment: Cross posted on [electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/76701/13513)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, and doesn't appear to have anything to do with verilog. What do you mean it's represented automatically in scientific notation? This is your code, you can type anything into it that you want.

Comment: How is `128'b1.84467e19: y=a64` appearing in the source code?

Comment: @Zoey show the code to used to generate the verilog code

Answer (score 2):

If only one bit of `s` is set (one-hot), you might be able to use "Constant expression in case statement" (see §12.5.2 of the free [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)):

```
case (1'b1)
    s[0]  : y=a1;
    s[1]  : y=a2;
    s[127]: y=a64;
endcase
```